# C# WPF SQL Server file download to PC

Tags: c#, wpf

```
byte[] fileData;
string fileName = "";

KitapArşivDataContext ka = new KitapArşivDataContext();

// Execute query to get actual file name of item.
var query = from tbl_PDF in ka.tbl_PDF
            where tbl_PDF.Id == 1 
            select tbl_PDF;

fileName = query.First().EserAdı;
fileData = (byte[])query.First().PDFFile.ToArray();

Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();

dlg.FileName = fileName;
dlg.Filter = "PDF Document|*.pdf |2007 Word Document|*.docx|Rich Text Format|*.rft";
dlg.Title = "Save Document";
        
// Show save file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
{
    System.IO.FileStream fs = (System.IO.FileStream)dlg.OpenFile();
    fs.Close();
}
```

I'm trying this code, but the file I downloaded comes empty. I think I need to write on filestream, but I don't know how to do it, I would be very happy if you could help.

Comment: [FileStream has a Write method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.write?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_FileStream_Write_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: i dont know how to do that can you give me an example

Comment: There is an "Examples" section at that link.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create a `MemoryStream` from your `fileData`. Then copy the data to the `FileStream`.

**Like this:**

```
   using(Stream stream=new MemoryStream(fileData))
 {
    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = (System.IO.FileStream)dlg.OpenFile())
    {
     stream.CopyTo(fs);
    } 
  }
```

Edit: As pointed out in the comment, you can simply use the `Write` method.

**Like this:**

```
fs.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
```

Comment: Why not just use it's `Write()` method?